# Invoking python functions

Tags: python

Trying to invoke the pay. I am doing something wrong on the "computepay()" invocation?

```
   hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
   hours = float(hrs)
   def computepay():
      p = computepay((hours>=40*10.5) + (hours>40*(10.5*1.5))
   computepay()
   pay = float(p)
   print("Pay",pay)
```

Comment: `computepay` is trying to call itself, and passing arguments that it doesn't accept. Also you have mismatched parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Your overall code logic doesn't make sense. Your function declaration and definition -  the way you call the function inside the function don't match.

```
def computepay():
```

The above code says `computepay()` doesn't take any argument.

```
p = computepay((hours>=40*10.5) + (hours>40*(10.5*1.5))
```

In this line of code, you are trying to call the function itself, but with arguments which it doesn't accept and hence you are getting the error.

Apart from this, neither does the argument that you are passing on that line makes much sense. You have called `computepay()` with argument - `(hours>=40*10.5) + (hours>40*(10.5*1.5)` but that won't work. `(hours>=40*10.5)` and `(hours>40*(10.5*1.5)` will evaluate to booleans and you can't add two boolean values.

I don't know what the logic is that you are trying to implement, but these are some major and obvious faults in your code that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

def computepay():
This function does not accept any parameters and has not been overloaded in any point of the code, so

```
computepay((hours>=40*10.5) + (hours>40*(10.5*1.5))
```

will not work. You can overload it in another section of the code as:

```
def computepay(argument):
```

but unless you do it so, it will never work. In addition

```
 (hours>=40*10.5)
```

this is a boolean value meaning that it is either true or false. You are trying to sum 2 boolean values, that also does not make sense. As far as I can see you are trying to implement recursion, hence your function invokes an instance of itself (or another unimplemented overloaded version) that will also not work because you do not have a base case. For more information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxiObVwQ8MM